# Surprisingly slow click event in React / Preact

Tags: javascript, performance, preact

I have the following component ([jsfiddle demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/bkgh64fm/1/)):

```
export function SomeComponent ()
{
    let t

    console.log("rendering...")

    return <div>
        <input
            type="text"
            defaultValue="value"
            onBlur={() => {
                t = performance.now()
                console.log("blur...")

                const el = document.getElementsByClassName("option")[0]
                var evObj = document.createEvent("Events")
                evObj.initEvent("click", true, false)
                el.dispatchEvent(evObj)
            }}
        />

        <div
            onClick={(e) => console.log("click...", e.isTrusted, performance.now() - t)}
            className="option"
        >Some Option</div>
    </div>
}
```

If I render it as the only component in an app, i.e.: `render(<SomeComponent />, root)` and if I then click on the input box and then click on the option box I see the following console output:

```
rendering...
blur...
click... false 0.5050000036135316
click... true 5.465000052936375  // <-- this is the actual click event
```

Why does the click, which triggered the blur event, take so much longer to start being handled?  And although I am not expecting there is, is there anyway to speed this up?

Tested in: Chrome, Brave, Firefox, Safari.

Preact: 10.5.7 and confirmed in React on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bkgh64fm/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a performance related issue.  The click event requires a `mousedown` followed up a `mouseup` event.  The first `mousedown` event happens first and triggers the `blur` event on the input followed, some time later when you release the mouse button, by the `mouseup` and the `click` event.  The time difference is predominantly how fast you can click the mouse! :)

[This code](https://jsfiddle.net/bkgh64fm/3/) shows the sequence of events:

```
function SomeComponent ()
{
    let t

    console.log("rendering...")

    return <div>
        <input
            type="text"
            defaultValue="value"
            onBlur={() => {
                t = performance.now()
                console.log("blur...")

                const el = document.getElementsByClassName("option")[0]

                var evObj = document.createEvent("Events")
                evObj.initEvent("mousedown", true, false)
                el.dispatchEvent(evObj)

                evObj = document.createEvent("Events")
                evObj.initEvent("mouseup", true, false)
                el.dispatchEvent(evObj)

                evObj = document.createEvent("Events")
                evObj.initEvent("click", true, false)
                el.dispatchEvent(evObj)
            }}
        />

        <div
            onMouseDown={(e) => console.log("mouse down...", e.isTrusted, performance.now() - t)}
            onMouseUp={(e) => console.log("mouse up...", e.isTrusted, performance.now() - t)}
            onClick={(e) => console.log("click...", e.isTrusted, performance.now() - t)}
            className="option"
        >Some Option</div>
    </div>
}


ReactDOM.render(
<SomeComponent />,
document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Which gives the output:

```
"mouse down...", true, NaN
"blur..."
"mouse down...", false, 1.459999941289425
"mouse up...", false, 2.7149999514222145
"click...", false, 10.524999932385981
"mouse up...", true, 12.214999995194376
"click...", true, 12.69000000320375
```